# Is there any way for correct replacement condition subqueries with JOINs and optimize those type queries?

Tags: mysql, join, optimization, subquery

I'm looking for any good way to optimize those queries by removing subqueries and reorganizing for possible indexes, but I stuck (

1-st

```sql
SELECT 
    `clients`.`name`,`clients`.`id`
FROM 
    `clients`
WHERE 
    `id` NOT IN (
        SELECT `orders`.`customer_id` FROM `orders` 
        WHERE `orders`.`order_date` BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND NOW()
    )
;
```

legend: "customers names who didn't place any order last 7 days"
(or didn't make any order at all)

looks good, works well but it makes me doubt ...

2-nd

```sql
SELECT 
    `clients`.`name`,`clients`.`id`,COUNT(*)
FROM 
    `clients`
INNER JOIN  `orders` ON
    `clients`.`id` = `orders`.`customer_id`   
        GROUP BY `orders`.`customer_id` ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC,`id` LIMIT 0,5;
```

legend: "top 5 customers who have made the most orders in the store"

any better idea? (

3-rd

```sql
SELECT 
     `clients`.`name`
     ,SUM(`merchandise`.`price`) as `TotalPrice`
     ,count(*)
FROM 
    `orders`
INNER JOIN  `clients` ON
    `orders`.`customer_id` = `clients`.`id`
INNER JOIN  `merchandise` ON
    `orders`.`item_id` = `merchandise`.`id`

GROUP BY 
    `orders`.`customer_id`
ORDER BY 
    `TotalPrice` DESC
LIMIT 
    0,10
;
```

legend: "top 10 customer names who made orders for the highest amount"

too slow solution ((( and have no idea about indices (

4-th

```sql
SELECT 
    `merchandise`.`name`
FROM
    `merchandise`
WHERE `id` NOT IN 
(
    SELECT
        `orders`.`item_id`
    FROM 
        `orders`
    WHERE 
        `orders`.`status` = 'complete'
)
;
```

legend: "names of all products for which there were no orders delivered"

again - subquery...

thank you for help and any ideas)

Comment: it would be better if you asked one question at a time

Comment: @scaisEdge, I'd decided it'd be better not spam with similar question types in same type. Thought it'd be better and more convenient for community members ((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, call me old-fashioned but I'd write the first query this way, with a composite index on (customer_id,order_date)

```
SELECT c.name
     , c.id
  FROM clients c
  LEFT
  JOIN orders o 
    ON o.customer_id = c.id
   AND o.order_date BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND NOW()
 WHERE o.id IS NULL;
```

The second query is fine, but I'd write it like this, again with the index mentioned above...

```
SELECT c.name
     , c.id
     , COUNT(*) total
  FROM clients c
  JOIN orders o
    ON o.customer_id = c.id 
 GROUP  
    BY c.name
     , c.id
 ORDER 
    BY total DESC
     , id 
 LIMIT 0,5;
```

Again, 3rd one seems fine. I find this easier to read:

```
SELECT c.name
     , SUM(m.price) TotalPrice
     , count(*) quantity
  FROM clients c
  JOIN orders o
    ON o.customer_id = c.id
  JOIN merchandise m
    ON m.id = o.item_id 
 GROUP 
    BY c.name
     , c.id
 ORDER 
    BY TotalPrice DESC
 LIMIT 0,10;
```

And identical to the first question (but with a composite index on (item_id,status), I'd write the fourth one like this - although NOT EXISTS may be faster:

```
SELECT m.name
  FROM merchandise m
  LEFT
  JOIN orders o
    ON o.item_id = m.id
   AND o.status = 'complete'
 WHERE o.item_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: thank you. And some benchmarks of old-fashioned way: 
1-st:

w/o index
  JOIN -  57,5845 seconds in avg., 
  SubQuery - 0,246 secs. avg. 

JOIN ~ 234 times slower

w index
  JOIN -  0,030 seconds in avg., 
  SubQuery - 0,203 avg. 

JOIN ~ 6,76 times faster

Comment: larger dataset more significant difference is

(with relatively small, for example, JOIN was even upto 500 times slower, and speedup benefit from index was only arr. 20%)


4-th
(with even larger dataset)

w/o index
  JOIN -  245,714 seconds in avg., 
  SubQuery - 0,438 secs. avg. 

JOIN ~ 561 times slower

w index
  JOIN -  0,015 seconds in avg., 
  SubQuery - 0,3745 avg. 

JOIN ~ 24,97 times faster

Comment: Resume:

Using old-way solutions is highly unrecommended w/o corresponding indices! It will cause dramatic slowdown and extremely huge load.

But, with indices they will be able to grant good performance boost, esp. on huge datasets


(benchmark produced on old 10G RAM notebook, with Ubuntu as OS and default configuration mysql-server 5.7.26)

Comment: sorry for bad formatting in comment body, i don't know why but  stack cutsoff newlines

Comment: but, strange thing second query is around 2 times slower - 1,191 sec vs 0,585 sec, and third around 15% (slower) - 3,854 sec vs 3,306 sec (((

Answer (score -1):

I believe the not in as function call and also joining an other table and let MySql Compare it might be a bit costy. For that I would have the program do the query joining the values and exclude the in the program. For the **2-nd** and **3-rd**, i believe you're doing the best possibility. Doing subqueries does cost more, as for the **first** and **fourth**, for those, as i mentioned before, i might just do one query joining the data I need and work with them on the program I am writing.

Comment: yes, subqueries and `in` / `not in` are relatively expensive enough.
at least if you've got correspondent indices. (in other case, they are not so bad and heavy as you can image at first sight).  but, no less a surprise for me was that the third request is extremely slow (for test data set - around 3+ seconds). And sadly, I can't find now neither good index, nor another solution (((